# Default Order Search

Tags: search, sales-order

How can I set the Sales Order search to by default only display "Processing" orders? So when I view the orders page it displays "Processing" orders by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the sales grid block and set a default filter to it.
For this you will need a custom module.
Let's call it `Easylife_Sales`.
It should contain the following files.

`app/etc/modules/Easylife_Sales.xml` - the declaration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Sales>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
                <Mage_Sales />
            </depends>
        </Easylife_Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Sales/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Easylife_Sales>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Easylife_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>Easylife_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid> <!-- rewrite the orders grid block-->
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Easylife/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php` - your new grid

```
<?php 
class Easylife_Sales_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid {
   protected $_defaultFilter = array('status'=>'processing'); //set a default filter
}
```

Clear the cache and give it a go.
I didn't test the code so watch out for typos and syntax errors.

Comment: Update: In `config.xml` you open `<blocks>` but close `</resources>`, after changing `</resources>` to `</blocks>` it works perfectly. Thank you so much! One typo isn't bad :)

Comment: @BenJackson. Sorry for that. Copy paste replace error. I fixed it. Thanks